# How to get effectively notified of issues on Google Cloud Platform (e.g. BigQuery)

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform

We have many production systems that are built on top of Google Cloud Platform, specifically using BigQuery. We have built error handling code, and incorporated all the usual best practices like back off and retry etc.

Sometimes however, there is an issue/outage on the Google Cloud Platform side of things which is out of our control. We'd like to be more pro-active to these types of outages, and somehow get notified of them as soon as possible so we can best mitigate them on our (application) side.

Is there any type of web hook, into knowing about issues on Google Cloud Platform?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google Cloud Platform has a RSS [status](https://status.cloud.google.com/) page that lists all known (and previous) issues on the platform. So you can either:

1. Subscribe the the [RSS feed](https://status.cloud.google.com/feed.atom) of this page using the RSS reader/app of your choice (we decided to create a dedicated Slack channel in our team hooked up to this).
2. Join the [Google Cloud Platform community on Slack](https://gcp-slack.appspot.com/) and join the `google-cloud-status` channel and which is wired up to the RSS feed.

This works well for us, and keeps us informed of issues/outages in a timely fashion.

Comment: Can you please explain a little bit more about the first point? Like how to subscribe?

Comment: Also, how does it works, like if a feed appears there is atm the service is failing or do you have to wait a while, to the feed to show up?